# SQL selecting rows using FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, relational-database

`suppliers` table:

```
PK_ID  supplier  supplier_code
  1       x           abc
  2       y           def
```

`items` table:

```
PK_ID   item_name   
 1        Name1           
 2        Name2
```

`items_suppliers` table with *FOREIGN KEYS*:

```
FK_ID_items  FK_ID_suppliers           
    1              1
    2              1
```

**I'd like to**:

Select ONE item and find other items with the same suppliers from `suppliers` table.
It should return "*Name2*" item then.

**[edited]**:

Take `ITEM1` and its **all** `suppliers` and find next `item` with every matched `supplier` **ONLY THEN** find next `item` with every `supplier` that matches.

---

**PROPER ANSWER (CREDIT TO @DarwinvonCorax - with @ThorstenKettner invaluable help):**

```
SELECT i2.item_name, s.supplier, s.supplier_code
FROM items i1
JOIN items_suppliers is1
ON i1.PK_ID = is1.FK_ID_items
JOIN items_suppliers is2
ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = is2.FK_ID_suppliers
JOIN items i2
ON is2.FK_ID_items = i2.PK_ID
JOIN suppliers s
ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = s.PK_ID
WHERE i1.item_name = 'Name1'
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN i2.item_name = 'Name1'
     THEN 1
     ELSE 2
  END,
i2.item_name, s.supplier;
```

**The solution proposed by @ThorstenKettner is also correct**:

```
select item_name
 from items
where pk_id in
(
 select fk_id_items
   from items_suppliers
  where fk_id_suppliers in
  (
    select fk_id_suppliers  
    from items_suppliers
    where fk_id_items = 
      (
       select pk_id from items where item_name = 'Name1')
      )
 );
```

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. Always use `join` for all tables. And `where` comes after `join`

Comment: I've edited SQL stmt but it returns suppliers of chosen `item`, not suprisingly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a palindromic join (my term.) First find the supplier ID for the specified item, then from `items_suppliers` find all records for the same supplier ID. You join `items` to `items_suppliers` to `items_suppliers` to `items`. Then tack on a join to `suppliers` at the end to get the supplier name.

Getting the forced sort order you want is a little trickier. I've used a hack I've seen elsewhere, but I honestly don't know how common it is. I do a `SELECT` to get just the suppliers for `Item1`, and add a constant column of value `1` to the result. I do a second `SELECT` to get the suppliers for all items *except* `Item1`, and add constant column `2`. `UNION` these two queries and from that result select just the columns you want, but `ORDER BY` the constant, which will sort all rows with value `1` (the suppliers for `Item1`) first.

```
SELECT item_name, supplier, supplier_code
  FROM
    (SELECT '1' AS orderer, i1.item_name AS item_name, s.supplier AS supplier, s.supplier_code AS supplier_code
      FROM items i1
      JOIN items_suppliers is1
        ON i1.PK_ID = is1.FK_ID_items
      JOIN suppliers s
        ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = s.PK_ID
      WHERE i1.item_name = 'Name1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', i2.item_name, s.supplier, s.supplier_code
      FROM items i1
      JOIN items_suppliers is1
        ON i1.PK_ID = is1.FK_ID_items
      JOIN items_suppliers is2
        ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = is2.FK_ID_suppliers
      JOIN items i2
        ON is2.FK_ID_items = i2.PK_ID
      JOIN suppliers s
        ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = s.PK_ID
      WHERE i1.item_name = 'Name1'
        AND i2.PK_ID <> i1.PK_ID
    ) r
  ORDER BY orderer, item_name, supplier;
```

Based on Thorsten Kettner's comments, though, I realize my SQL is just a little rusty and out-of-date; his suggestion would look something like this:

```
SELECT i2.item_name, s.supplier, s.supplier_code
  FROM items i1
  JOIN items_suppliers is1
    ON i1.PK_ID = is1.FK_ID_items
  JOIN items_suppliers is2
    ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = is2.FK_ID_suppliers
  JOIN items i2
    ON is2.FK_ID_items = i2.PK_ID
  JOIN suppliers s
    ON is1.FK_ID_suppliers = s.PK_ID
  WHERE i1.item_name = 'Name1'
  ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN i2.item_name = 'Name1'
         THEN 1
         ELSE 2
      END,
    i2.item_name, s.supplier;
```

Comment: It works but there's big **BUT**. If `item` = *Name1* has more `suppliers`' pairs - it returns other item names for every supplier pair value e.g: Name1 and other items with suppliers(PK_ID=1) then again Name1 and other items but with suppliers(PK_ID=4)

Comment: If `Name1` has multiple suppliers, the query will return all items from each supplier. That's what your question asked for.

Comment: but it returns it in looped fashion: 1. Take (`Name1` and its **FIRST** `supplier`) -> 2. Show other `NameX` with taken `supplier` and show only **ONE** `supplier` -> 3. Take (`Name2` and its **now SECOND** `supplier`) etc...

Comment: What I'd like to have: take `ITEM1` and its **all** `suppliers` and find next `item` with every matched `supplier` **ONLY THEN** find next `item` with every `supplier` that matches.

Comment: So you want to see all suppliers for `Item1`, then all suppliers for `Item2` etc.? If that's correct I can do it, but it will be a bit ugly.

Comment: Exactly! `ITEM1` and in rows below: `ITEM1` and its `supplier1`, row below `ITEM1` and its `supplier2` - that again for `ITEM2` if one of its suppliers matched the `ITEM1` :)

Comment: @SQLnoob: Are you merely talking about the order in which the result rows are to be shown? Add `ORDER BY i2.item_name, s.supplier` then.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's a bit more complex than that; he wants to force `Item1` to sort first, as I understand it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner *et al*: See my revised solution. I think it will do what you want.

Comment: @Darwin von Corax: It would probably have been easier to add `ORDER BY CASE WHEN i2.item_name = 'Name1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, i2.item_name, s.supplier` :-)

Comment: Instead of the outer `SELECT`? Yeah, probably; when I learned SQL that wasn't an option, though, so I never think of it.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your time and work :) Now that I'm thinking about it - it should be easier to divide process into 3 steps and fetch results in PHP: **1**. Find `FK_ID_suppliers` for desired `item` -> **2**. Find `FK_ID_items` for each `FK_ID_suppliers` from step 1 -> **3**. For each `FK_ID_items` from step 2, find `suppliers` - a @ThorstenKettner reply. I'm wondering what would be faster :)

Comment: In the new query `UNION` should be replaced by `UNION ALL`. `UNION` wants to remove duplicates, but there can be none (orderer is '1' in the first part and '2' in the second). In any way here are two queries that get glued together; the first explicitely selecting Name1, the second explicitely not selecting it. It would be faster to select them all in one go, as was the query before alteration, and then simply sort the resulting rows as desired.

Comment: And of course it is faster to send one select statement to the DBMS and get the complete results back, than send one query, wait for the results, build a second query from the results in PHP, send this to the DBMS and so on. The DBMS is made to get the data from several tables. It would make no sense to neglect this service and try to mimic it somehow - it will never become as fast.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Good point about selecting in one go. I've added an alternate solution using that new-fangled "conditional sort" thing. :P

Comment: It's against rules here but whatever! It's SEXY. Your edited alternate solution works like a charm and IT IS SEXY. Thank you both! You are the best.

Comment: You're welcome. I learned a thing or two on this one as well.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Pretty complex ;-) nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Do that step by step:

1. Find the item ID for item 'Name1'.
2. Find all suppliers for that item ID.
3. Find all item IDs of these suppliers.
4. Find the item names for the found IDs.

The query:

```
select item_name
from items
where pk_id in
(
  select fk_id_items
  from items_suppliers
  where fk_id_suppliers in
  (
    select fk_id_suppliers  
    from items_suppliers
    where fk_id_items = (select pk_id from items where item_name = 'Name1')
  )
);
```

You can add `and item_name <> 'Name1'` if you want to exclude that from your list.

Comment: It works **BUT** then again: if I select `supplier` and `supplier_code` to first row of your stmt it returns results in loop - it's taking into account one `supplier` and is looking for other items with this `supplier` and once again next `supplier` and once again is looking for other items with this supplier... I believe there's simpler solution, maybe with `JOIN` where all results are shown at once - but thanks for **working reply** and step-by-step instruction, it helps

Comment: What I'd like to have: take `ITEM1` and its **all** `suppliers` and find next `item` with every matched `supplier` **ONLY THEN** find next `item` with every `supplier` that matches.

Comment: You make this sound like a recursion, but it's simply a step-by-step approach: Get the item, get its suppliers, get their items. How else would you address this problem? The query is straight-forward and should result in a good execution plan. You can do the same with some joins of course, which is not as straight-forward, however. EDIT: This is the answer to your first comment. I am reading the second right now ...

Comment: As to your second comment: It seems you are trying to find the best algorithm to access the table records. But this is not your job and it is not how SQL works. In SQL you only tell the DBMS *what* to select (and you use the most simple and readable query for this), then let the DBMS find the best access method. It is made for this job, so trust it to do it well.

Comment: I feel like it can be simplified with `JOIN`s :) Close to be perfect.

Comment: So my query's result is correct, but you think joins would be better? As mentioned, it is possible but not as straight-forward. That would be Darwin von Corax' query. Remove `, s.supplier, s.supplier_code` from the select list and add `DISTINCT`: `SELECT DISTINCT i2.item_name FROM items i1 ...`. This can produce quite a big intermediate result, which you then compress with `DISTINCT`. Possible, but not really good.

Comment: It is especially beginners who tend to join all tables first and then think about what they actually want to select later. This leads to less readable and thus less maintainable queries. And sometimes this leads to trouble when it comes to aggregations. (This doesn't criticize Darwin's answer by the way; his joins are necessary, because he wants to show the suppliers, too, not only the item names.)

Comment: I can't mark or even mark the answer as useful (newbie status) but I've added your response to main post - also your step-by-step instruction gave me the idea to use PHP.

Comment: That's okay. The answer is here and others with the same problem can find it and decide which solution to use. Don't use PHP when you can do it in SQL, however. Database systems are written to access the data in an optimal way. If you only let it select intermediate results, data is accessed in a less optimal way. More work for you, usually worse to read and maintain and much slower.